# How to install Windows 8 in Ubuntu machine?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I have a computer running Ubuntu 12.04 and would like to dual boot Windows 8. Is this possible without harming the Ubuntu installation? Everywhere I have looked said to install windows 8 first. Thanks

Comment: Is Ubuntu installed in BIOS boot mode with MBR(msdos) partitioning? Windows will need a primary partition formatted NTFS with the boot flag. You also have to turn off fast boot or hibernation with Windows 8 or you will have issues.

Comment: @Braiam He doesn't have a dual boot system. So that is not the ideal question to link as dupe.

Comment: @Lucio he accepted an answer that is just a link to that question. How is not ideal?

Comment: @Braiam At least you could mention why do you think that it is a possible duplicated.

Comment: @Lucio He needs to install Windows 8, right? Windows will mess the GRUB for good, then he will need to repair it. The answer will help him to bring the GRUB back after installing Windows (it doesn't matter if he had or not dual-boot, the GRUB will be messed up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But you have to reinstall GRUB after Windows installation. This manual will help: 
[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: In this site is a dedicated post about recovering the GRUB: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows